# Rails not serving compressed SVG files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, compression, asset-pipeline, assets

I’ve been using Google PageSpeed to optimize my Rails 5.0 application, and something odd jumped out with SVGs in particular. I use `Rack::Deflate` to compress static assets like so...

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
```

...and yet Google PageSpeed was nevertheless complaining about uncompressed SVGs being served.

I thought this was weird, so I added some [code](https://gist.github.com/derekclee/459f2091e34bc38c9231) to manually compress SVGs as part of asset precompilation. This works perfectly, and I can go to http://myapp.com/sample_image.svg.gz and indeed I get the compressed image file.

However, Google PageSpeed is *still* complaining about uncompressed assets being served.

It would appear that, just like how Rails 5.0 wasn’t *compressing* my SVGs, when I compress them manually, it still won’t *serve* them.

Is there some kind of configuration I need to adjust here to get the compressed SVG files to be served correctly?

Comment: It seems that Rails' ActionDispatch::Static middleware [doesn't recognize svg as a valid format for serving gzipped](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb#L89), despite the fact that Sprockets does generate .gz versions of svg files. The regex on the highlighted line would have to be changed to change the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I started a [discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8e31fa3b72892f7421b85b5a79d71a2d726ccddd#commitcomment-23933895) about how to resolve this in a comprehensive way, since this also seems to affect font & json files that sprockets will compress but ActionDispatch::Static won't serve. Anyway, here's a solution via a monkeypatch (put in an initializer):

```
require 'action_dispatch/middleware/static'

ActionDispatch::FileHandler.class_eval do
  private

    def gzip_file_path(path)
      return false if ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'].include? content_type(path)
      gzip_path = "#{path}.gz"
      if File.exist?(File.join(@root, ::Rack::Utils.unescape_path(gzip_path)))
        gzip_path
      else
        false
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: You mentioned you started a discussion about how to resolve this in a comprehensive way. Can you please add a link to that discussion here?

Comment: @nnc thanks for the reminder! The discussion is on [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8e31fa3b72892f7421b85b5a79d71a2d726ccddd#commitcomment-23933895)

Answer (score 2):

This is still true for Rails 6.1. I've made a PR to fix this: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42407

Comment: More than 2 years later, the PR got merged: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/50359